# Create a new app registration linked to an existing enterprise app in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azureportal

Have an existing enterprise app provisioned on Azure that I would like "linked" to a new app registration, for the purpose of adding permissions.  When I create a new app registration, there is no way for me to specify an existing client id-- it always creates a new one.  Is it possible to create a new registration app and linking it to an existing enterprise app, or moving the existing enterprise app over to a new registration?  If not, is there a way to add new permissions, both delegates and applications, to an existing enterprise app?

Comment: Are you trying to define new custom permissions and roles for this application? or just trying to add more permissions for another api like say extra delegated permissions (or application permissions) for Microsoft Graph API in addition to what this app already has?

Comment: the latter: add extra delegated and application permissions

Comment: ok got it.. then changing in current app registration should be good.. is there any specific reason you're asking about linking to a new app registration?

Comment: that's the thing, there is no app registration for the enterprise app.

Comment: **1)** Look under "All Applications" in app registrations. Screenshot with "All Applications" selected https://i.stack.imgur.com/o16Ob.png **2)** Is it a multi-tenant application which was registered in a different Azure AD tenant but given an Admin consent in your Azure AD tenant(that you're currently looking at)?.. In such case, you will only see an Enterprise Application entry but not find an app registration. This is usual for multi-tenant SaaS applications that your organization uses/takes subscription for, but app has been developed by someone else and hence registered in their Azure AD